# Keep kerberos ticket across sudo invocation

Tags: sudo, kerberos, afs

On a regular linux machine, when I use `sudo -s` as a normal user, I become root but `HOME` still points to `~user`, so every admin has his own environment etc. (this is without `env_reset` or `always_set_home` set).

On a system where the home directories live on an AFS file system, this also works, if the environment variable `KRB5CCNAME` is preseved, as root can read this file in `/tmp`.

But if I use `sudo` on such a system to change a local non-root user (e.g. the dedicated user for a certain service), the new user cannot access the kerberos cache (as it is owned by the old user and has mode 600). But if I `unset KRB5CCNAME && kinit user && aklog && exec bash`, I have access to my environment again.

So the question is: Is there a clean way to make sudo take the kerberos tickets that I had before and add them to the kerberos ticket cache of the new user?

Comment: Do you want access to your original user's Kerberos Cache?  Or do you want the new session as the non-root user to have AFS tokens from the original user?

Comment: Either would work. I guess granting access to my cache to other users might be more difficult security-wise, so I am fine with my tickets being copied.

Comment: Well, the question I'm really asking is do you need the Kerberos tickets for some other non-AFS function, or do you just want to run a session as a new user with access to your AFS files as the old user?  AFS tokens are stored in the user's PAG, while the kerberos cache can be easily copied around.

Comment: AFS access is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there's any current support for this in any of the Kerberos PAM modules that I'm aware of.  I can see how it could be implemented, though; there's nothing inherently impossible about it.  Basically, `pam_krb5` would need to gain code to open a ticket cache pointed to by the current `KRB5CCNAME`, iterate through it, and copy each ticket found into the newly-created ticket cache after initial cache setup.

This would need to be a non-default option, since you would be giving away your credentials to the target user (including to anyone *else* who can become that user), which is potentially dangerous.

If you need an immediate solution, consider using `ksu` instead if you don't need all of the power of `sudo`.  `ksu` already has support for keeping the current Kerberos ticket cache (at least in the MIT Kerberos version).